# function execution related question

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sql-developer

```
Create or replace function funleap(a number)
return varchar2
is
   b2 number(5);
   b3 number(5);
   b4 number(5);
begin
    b2:=mod(a,4);
    b3:=mod(a,100);
    b4:=mod(a,400);
    if ((b2=0 and b3<>0) or (b4=0)) then
       dbms_output.put_line(a||'is leap year');
    else
       dbms_output.put_line(a||'is not a leap year');
    end if;

    return b2;
    return b3;
    return b4;
 end;
 /

 select FUNLEAP(1904) from dual;
 * this function executes properly,
```

I am trying to understand  what the `return` statement does, how it works internally. If I specify the argument of 1904, then it shows me that it's a leap year, but what do the three `return` statements do there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return is basically translated as:

"End execution of this routine, and pass control back to the caller .. oh, and hand this value back to them on the way .."

So that code will NEVER reach the "return b3" or "return b4" ... 
just won't happen.

also, this might be more "robust" logic for checking for a leap year ;)

```
if add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YEAR'),2)-1 =
   add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YEAR'),1)+28 then
  dbms_output.put_line ( 'Leap year' );
else
  dbms_output.put_line ( 'Not a leap year' );
end if;
```

(I used sysdate, just change it to your passed in date ... )